# How to disable NTLM proxy auth in Java?

Tags: java, spring, jvm, feign

I am trying to run Spring app with Feign http client inside. App is behind proxy. 
I set following JVM parameters:

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="NTLM"
-Dhttps.proxySet=true
-Dhttps.proxyHost=${JAVA_PROXY_HOST}
-Dhttps.proxyPort=${JAVA_PROXY_PORT}
```

My corporate proxy is offering NTLM and Basic authentication, but I should use Basic only. I Added `NTLM` to disabled tunneling schemes but it looks app is ignoring it - it always try to use NTLM. How can I enforce application wide use of  Basic authentication for proxy?

Comment: Are you using spring cloud openfeign ? or pure feign client ?

Comment: I am using Openfeign